# Unable launch chrome driver version 123.0.6312.59 using selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

Got below error when run selenium in chrome version `123.0.6312.59` :

```
Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
```

Current chrome browser version is `123.0.6312.59`

below are my selenium and webdrivermanager decencies :

```xml
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>4.11.0</version>
```

```xml
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>5.4.1</version>
```

my expectation should be chrome launch using the latest chrome version

Comment: Try updating selenium version to `4.18.1` and WDM to `5.7.0`

Comment: Hi Shawn,  Thanks for replying my issue and yes issue has been fixed after update the selenium and wdw.

Answer (score 0):

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Chrome labs has several versions of Chromedriver for the newest Chrome browser update.

1. Find out your OS.
2. Download the appropriate zip folder for your OS.
3. Replace the executable where ever you store the old executable for Chromedriver.

You should be good to go from there!

I ran into the same issue after the newest update.

Answer (score 0):

The below dependency is not required while using Chrome versions grater than 122 onwards. Remove this, it should work.

```
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>5.4.1</version>
```